# how to vertically align a <input> and <iframe> inside a <td>?

Tags: iframe, input, valign

I've tried putting valign="top" as attribute of `<td>` but in vain.

```
<tr>
<td>
    <span class="validationInline">*</span>
    Security Code:
</td>
<td valign="top">
    <input type="text" />
    <iframe scrolling="no" height="21px" frameborder="0" width="62px" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
</td>
</tr>
```

It seems that `<input>` aligns itself to the buttom,while `<iframe>` to the top.

Comment: I would clean this up a little more, or make it a `community wiki` so we can improve it without reposting.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems that the cell *is* aligning to the top, but the input/iframe are aligning to each other at the bottom. Vertical alignment generally only applies to sibling elements.

What you'll need to do is set the CSS `vertical-align:top` property on both the input and iframe.

```
<td valign="top">
  <input style="vertical-align:top" type="text" />
  <iframe style="vertical-align:top" scrolling="no" height="18" frameborder="0" width="62" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://google.com"> </iframe>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td valign="top"><input type="text" />
  <iframe scrolling="no" height="18" frameborder="0" width="62" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://google.com"> </iframe></td>
```

The above works for me... It aligns the content to the top of the cell. Is this what you're after?

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your entire table, or at least the entire row?

Comment: It's exactly the same as your snippet.

Comment: No, I was asking you for the rest of the table, or at least rest of the row...

Re-reading your question, what is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: I've pasted the entire row here.